# Could I write this more concisely?

Tags: jquery, optimization

how Could I write this more concisely?

This is the list of buttons, all of them do the same thing, changing some css property, but in the different places

```
$('#right-panel li:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
        $('#pom03par01WraperAbsolute').css('display','block');
        $(this).css('background','#adff84');
        $('.par01table').css('background','#adff84');
        return false;
    }); 
    $('#right-panel li:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
        $('#pom03par02WraperAbsolute').css('display','block');
        $(this).css('background','#adff84');
        $('.par02table').css('background','#adff84');
        return false;
    }); 
    $('#right-panel li:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
        $('#pom03par03WraperAbsolute').css('display','block');
        $(this).css('background','#adff84');
        $('.par03table').css('background','#adff84');
        return false;
    }); 
    $('#right-panel li:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
        $('#pom03par04WraperAbsolute').css('display','block');
        $(this).css('background','#adff84');
        $('.par04table').css('background','#adff84');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: first thing I think of is adding a class to the relevant elements and have the one function that changes the css of the clicked element of that class.

Comment: http://codrerview.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You mean http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: if the the html layout is important, show it.

Comment: Both of you mean http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one using jQuery each:

```
$('#right-panel li')each(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).click(function(){
            if(i<9){
                  i = "0"+i;
             }
             $('#pom03par' + i + 'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
             $(this, '.par' + i + 'table').css('background','#adff84');
             return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: How do you know that they want to change all the children? Maybe there are more than four `<li>`'s

Comment: @JamesHill You're right James but that can be easily modified with an if statement

Comment: @Alfonso your code works fine but i need one change, how to change index from 0 to 1, first element need to has index 1 not 0

Comment: what if there are more than 9 elements and "'#pom03par0' + i" need to be "'#pom03par' + i" and i dont want to change names of all id's ??

Comment: Well, there are two options, you can get rid of the id's and make the code more generic, but in that case I need to see the HTML structure, otherwise I can do a quick fix to the code above if you want (Already edited).

Comment: i need to use id's cause every element will be connect with different cell from excell file so it has to be id's, if you're so kind and fix the code above it will be awesome!

Comment: so simple :], this was a very productive day, THX all and above all you Alfonso

Comment: Just remember some basic rules, if you are writing a piece of code more than twice you can always create some sort of loop. In terms of jQuery syntax if you are applying the same function in two places (like css in your case) you can group them into one. Yo won't see the difference in small apps but on big ones it saves cpu cycles. Have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**

Use a `for loop` and build your selectors dynamically:

```
var numberOfChildren = 4;

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfChildren; i++) {
    $('#right-panel li:nth-child(' + i + ')').click(function() {
        $('#pom03par0' + i + 'WraperAbsolute').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).css('background', '#adff84');
        $('.par0' + i + 'table').css('background', '#adff84');
        return false;
    });
}​
```

**Option 2:**

You seem to be doing the same thing to each element. Simply assign each element the same class and manipulate it by that class.

**Additional Information**

It may also be beneficial for you to read [jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Comment: this is awesome!, works perfectly, i need to use id's, THX mate

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it looks like the 4 parts do basically the same thing. You can use the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method on the $(this) selector to find out which LI was actually clicked on, this returns a zero based number. I've created a jsFiddle for you to have a look at below.

```
$('#test ul li').click(function() {
    index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('[id$=WraperAbsolute]').css("background-color", "green");
    $('#pom03par' + index + 'WraperAbsolute').css("background-color", "red");
    //alert("clicked: " + index);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xym7U/)

Comment: Alfonso code with your + 1 after .index() is correct answer, THX ALL GUYS

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes.  Any time you feel yourself about to hit Ctrl-C, resist that urge and type "function" instead.

The background line is repeated verbatim.  The only real different is the pom number and the par number.  Those could be your arguments to a new function.  You could even leave room to expand, for example to allow passing in your background color if the default (#adff84) isn't what you want.